# How to create a Customized Menu for Link Manager to display under the Nav in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Let me see if I can explain this correctly.

I have a wordpress blog setup, I have my main menu  code in my header.php listed below.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'menu_class' => 'nav' ) ); ?>
```

Now what I am looking for is the same type of menu but it will carry my Categories from the Links manager.  Currently what I am using is the code below but that only gives me the links.

```
<?php wp_list_bookmarks('title_li=&categorize=0'); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to replace the links in your main menu?  Or are you adding a 2nd menu for your cat links?

If you are trying to replace the existing links in your main menu, you can do that by going to your dashboard > appearance > menus.  Make sure you're editing the Main menu and simply remove the existing links and add new links found within the 'categories' dropdown option.

You can add an additional menu by adding code to your functions file, building the menu within your dashboard (just as you would the main menu), and adding the new menu to your header template.

If you open your function.php file, you should find something like this:

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() for primary and footer links.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'YOURTHEMENAME' ),
        'footer' => __( 'Footer Links', 'YOURTHEMENAME' ),
    ) );
```

Modify it to add your new menu, i.e.:

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() for primary and footer links.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'YOURTHEMENAME' ),
        'mycatlinks' => __( 'Category Menu', 'YOURTHEMENAME' ),
        'footer' => __( 'Footer Links', 'YOURTHEMENAME' ),
    ) );
```

Don't miss any of those commas!

Save your function file, go to the menu builder, and create a new menu.  Add the category links you want to include.  Be sure to check the box for 'Category Menu' as the new menu location. Save the menu.

Now go to your header.php file and add the new menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'mycatlinks' ) ); ?>
```

Save header.php, refresh your page, and you should see the new menu!  The only thing bad about this method is that the menu will not automatically update as new categories are added - you'll have to go back and add them manually within the menu builder.  But you shouldn't have too many categories anyway.... that's what tags are for!

Hope this helps.  Have a good Friday!